# How to wipe user apps, user data, user cache in non-rooted android devices using adb commands?

Tags: android, command, adb

I want to wipe all user apps, user data and user cache of an android device by using adb commands.
The android device is NOT rooted. 
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this you can not achieve this on non-rooted device because by default android system is read-only file system .

Just try this:

1:Start AVD.

2:Run "adb shell" command in terminal.

3:After that try to remove anyone file from system . It shows read-only file system error.

If you want to root your avd : http://www.spinachsoftware.com/blog/?p=224

Thanks.

Comment: Thank You.. I had already wipe everything from rooted emulator but it is not useful for those devices which are connected via usb hub because those devices are not rooted.

Comment: I dont want to root device. I simply want to do it on non rooted device only.

Comment: It's not possible because it is not permitted by Android system.